# Using environment variables to fill a Map in a @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this @ConfigurationProperties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class CustomProperties {

    private Map<String, String> namespace = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getNamespace() {
        return namespace;
    }
}
```

Before I start the application, I put these arguments as a program arguments:

```
--myapp.namespace.namespace1.connection="xxxx"
--myapp.namespace.namespace1.url="yyy"
--myapp.namespace.namespace2.topic="zzz"
--myapp.namespace.namespace2.id="ccc"
```

And it works successfully, the namespace map will contain four entries:

```
{namespace2.id=ccc, namespace1.connection=xxxx, namespace2.topic=zzz, namespace1.url=yyy}
```

Now I am "dockerizing" the application. How can I make it work with environment variables? I tried:

```
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1.CONNECTION="xxxx"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1.URL="yyy"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE2.TOPIC="zzz"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE2.ID="ccc"
```

and

```
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION="xxxx"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_URL="yyy"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE2_TOPIC="zzz"
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE2_ID="ccc"
```

And it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Thanks Fernando.

Comment: Are you sending these environment variables through docker run command or using docker-compose? Could you please edit the post and make clear.

Comment: I'm using ConfigMaps of Kubernetes to send it. It works with a single String but not with Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone else using Kubernetes, there is a simpler way, than environment variables, to inject complex config into spring boot applications. We can have a config map entry named `application.yml` with the required config, inject the entry into the container through a volume and set the environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION` to point to that location

**Steps:**

- Create a config map named `demo-config` which contains a multi-line data with the key `application.yml`
- Create a volume named `config-volume` from config map demo-config mapping only the data key `application.yml`
- Mount the config volume into the container at `/etc/config`
- Set the environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION` to `/etc/config/` - the trailing slash is required
- The app starts up, reads the config from `/etc/config/application.yml` and logs the line `com.example.demo.AppProps - Namespace: {namespace2.id=ccc, namespace1.connection=xxxx, namespace2.topic=zzz, namespace1.url=yyy}`

**Test Configuration class:**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class AppProps {

    private Map<String, String> namespace = new HashMap<>();
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Namespace: {}", namespace);
    }
}
```

**Config map:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-config
data:
  application.yml: |
    myapp:
      namespace:
        namespace1.connection: xxxx
        namespace1.url: yyy
        namespace2.topic: zzz
        namespace2.id: ccc
```

**Deployment:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: demo-config
            items:
              - key: application.yml
                path: application.yml
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: devatherock/demo:0.1.0-local.1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config  
          env:
           - name: SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION
             value: "/etc/config/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map these properties to the environment variables in spring profile i.e. application or bootstrap properties *(like in application.properties/yml or bootstrap.properties/yml file)* by using the placeholders. You can map to the environment variable placeholders as below. These will resolve to the corresponding environment variable.

```
myapp.namespace.namespace1.connection=${MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION}
myapp.namespace.namespace1.url=${MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION}
myapp.namespace.namespace2.topic=${MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION}
myapp.namespace.namespace2.id=${MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE2_ID}
```

**If you know know the properties name in advance and know only the prefix:**

You only need to map with one placeholder and provide environmental variables by appending that placeholder and with underscores like:

```
myapp.namespace=${MYAPP_NAMESPACE}
```

If you provide env variable,

```
MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION=xxx
```

Springboot is smart enough to resolve this to

```
myapp.namespace.namespace1.connection==xxx
```

You just have to follow the convention to use underscores (_) only which will be resolved to dots (.).

We are using it in our application. I also tested this particular scenario and when it prints the namespaces as below:

```
{namespace1.connection=xxxx}
```

I hope I understood correctly what you want to achieve here.

Comment: They will be properties that I don't know in advance.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Let me know if I did not understand your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can initialize it just by doing @Value("${MYAPP_NAMESPACE_NAMESPACE1_CONNECTION}") or whatever the key in your env var is

Then give it the variable you want it in like so

```
@Value("${variable}")
private String variable;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution with Map, not a single String.

Comment: There's a chance I didn't understand your question, but all the properties are strings right? You're just storing the key as the variable and the value as the value of the variable.

Comment: They will be properties that I don't know in advance.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I missed that part, can you use the System.getProperties() function?